# Is an element that is returning to itself Transitive?

Tags: equivalence-relations

Lets say you have a graph and x goes to y, y goes to itself and then y goes back to x. Can you call this a transitive relation?

My answer: yes it is transitive because x R y, y R y and y R x but what confuses me is that I learned transitivity as follows:

if x R y and y R z then x R z. But in the case above x R x if you reason like this. If find this a bit confusing. Can anyone please explain this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have $x \to y$ and $y \to x$ so for $\to$ to be transitive you must also have $x \to x$. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes, this is the case. So it does not matter whether that element is not unique? I have x -> y and y -> x and also x->x.

Comment: Whether what element is unique?

Comment: If x goes to x then it is back where it was. I thought z cannot be x. But this is allowed?

Comment: Yes, that's allowed.